# CSS Active menu item not working?

Tags: html, css

I have read numerous StackOverflow threads on this topic, but they don't seem to work for me, could I please ask you to have a look at what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="c menu-accordion">
<ul>
  <a href="#">
       <li class="yellow">Menu Item 5 </li>
  </a>
</ul>
</div>

.bkg-yellow,
.menu-accordion ul li.yellow {
background:#f5a906;
 }

.menu-accordion ul li.yellow:active {
background:#000;
}
```

I would like the Selected list item to remain black once selected / active. At the moment, if I hold my mouse click down on the list item, it turns black, but when I release, it goes back to the original color.

See the fiddle I created as an example. http://jsfiddle.net/eAhac/4/

Comment: you need to add a class to LI via jquery/ javascript to make that selected. this is not possible with CSS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said earlier and adding Jacek comment of re-structuring your code  [check this Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eAhac/5/)

```
$('li').click(function(){
  $('li').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML isn't valid. I should propose something like that for HTML5

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/" title="Title MUST be here also">LINK</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then, active pseudoclass should be applied to anchor, like that:

```
nav ul li a:active {background: #f00;}
```

But it will work only for a moment that item is clicked I think :).

**UPDATE**
If You need to save clicked elements, and anchors have event prevent default, You should add class to them using on click event (JQuery). Then clicked elements will have additional class and another color / background. If You need code, please write :).

*"Tip: Use the :link selector to style links to unvisited pages, the :visited selector to style links to visited pages, and the :hover selector to style links when you mouse over them."*

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Hope it helps